# Help finding prior art for US13/135,467 (3D computer graphics object and method)

Tags: prior-art, prior-art-request

This application (US13135467) is attempting to patent a broad concept of defining "templates" of graphical objects using natural language text: https://www.google.com/patents/US20130009944

Not only is this obvious and not new, but other companies like Microsoft have done this for years. This pHD paper from a Microsoft researcher is from 2006 (the application in question is from 2011) and covers the same idea:

ftp://ftp.heanet.ie/disk1/download.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/v/ve/vedaviz/text%20to%203d%20animation%20PhD%20-%20m%20a%20thesis.pdf

I have submitted a form to USPTO using their "Third-Party Preissuance Submission under 37 CFR 1.290" process but it got rejected because I did not state the "The concise description of relevance is missing or is improper" criteria was not met.

Perhaps someone with more experience filing these forms can help me out? Or, perhaps, even more obvious prior art exists. It would be a shame if this was patented because it seems very general.

Comment: I think this belongs on the main Ask Patents site, not on the meta site. I do have a substantive comment/answer if it is reposted or migrated.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite it was moved.

Comment: This patent seems to be reaching for coverage of areas in natural language processing (extracting semantic relations among objects in a natural language) as well as of object-oriented design (though it speaks of "graphical object" everywhere, what is being described are really OO objects: entities with names and attributes that are themselves similar entities.)  From NLP to an object structure, to rules which render the implied 3D object.